# See other schema's tables in SqlDeveloper

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

When I connect to an Oracle DB with user XXX I see the tables, packages, etc. in schema XXX.
Is there a way so that I can connect with user XXX and see things in another schema YYY?

When I browse objects in SQLDeveloper I can see in the statement log that it sends XXX as parameter like "SCHEMA"="XXX", so I would just need to trick sqlDeveloper to use "SCHEMA"="YYY".

Answer (score 3):

If you have the correct privileges to see the objects in other schemas you can see them by expanding the connection in the connections tab and looking for Other Users and you will be able to see all other users objects.

You can also start with the schema prefix and use that to see and access objects in other schemas.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way so that I can connect with user XXX and see things in another schema YYY?

As you correctly state, when you connect to a database using account "X", the "tree" in SqlDeveloper shows you the objects owned by "X".

There is also an entry, near the bottom, named "Other Users".

Under *there* lie all the *other* accounts in the database (i.e. "other" than the one you're connected as).  Expanding these entries will show you objects owned by these accounts ...   *as long as* you have permission to access (read/select) them!

To have a similar effect in the *Query Window*, use the "alter session" statement:

```
select count( * ) c from Y.table1 ; 

alter session set current_schema = Y ; 
select count( * ) c from   table1 ;
```